# How do you pass object data into textboxes in a second form to edit?

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, object, textbox

I am relatively new to C# and I could use some help with getting over this hurdle. I have a windows form along with classes to that will create call objects with values entered by the user and add them to a list. I would like to take an existing call and display its values in different text boxes in a seperate form that is opened when I click a button. I have a 'FindCall' method that finds the desired call in the list by its 'callerName' and 'phoneNumber' values. If the call is successfully found it will display the edit form. This works fine and the form opens, so I know that the code to find the call is functioning properly. However I cannot wrap my head around how I can display values of that call object in the text boxes on that edit form. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Give that 2nd form a Property with a setter and give it a value when you instantiate the form prior to showing it.  Or pass it via the Form's constructor to a private property.  Either will work fine.

Comment: add a variable and upon calling second form assign that variable value to text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do that would be to create a property on the second form.  This will allow you to set the values on the form before displaying it and get any new values afterwards.

On the edit form have something like...

```
string SomeValue
{
    get { return SomeValueField.Text; }
    set { SomeValueField.Text = value; }
}
```

...where `SomeValueField` is a TextBox on the edit form.

Then in the calling form you can access the TextBox via the property...

```
var editForm = new EditForm();

editForm.SomeValue = "...";

editForm.ShowDialog();

var newValue = editForm.SomeValue;
```

Comment: This worked like a charm for the name property, however when trying to use int and DateTime even with attempted conversion I cannot get it to work. I get a FormatException when I click the find call button saying the input string was not in a correct format. It highlights my set for the PhoneNumber property 'value = Convert.ToInt32(phonenumber_txt.Text);'. The same thing happens to the DateTime property. Many Thanks.

Comment: The `value` variable in the `set` accessor is the actual value you've given it when you do `.PhoneNumber = ...`.  Since you're using it to set the value of a TextBox, you need `phonenumber_txt.Text = value;`.  It's the `get` accessor where you need to convert the string value in the TextBox back to the type you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have helped me immensely. I had to add a .ToString() to the end of value but that was simple enough :)

Answer (score 0):

So you have a form let's call it Form1 that opens up a new Form lets call it Form2 using something like this.

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 _newForm = new Form2();
        _newForm.Show();
    }
```

All you need to do is inside Form2 create a public void that passes through a string to set the value of your text box so in Form2 you have:

```
    public void SetTextBox(string _txt)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = _txt;
    }
```

Then you change your Form1 code to include:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 _newForm = new Form2();
        _newForm.SetTextBox("Your Text Here");
        _newForm.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Methods are fine, but overkill for something as simple as passing a string.